# SQL analytic ORACLE Converting rows into columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table structue which has 2 columns as mentioned below

```
Column_name    old Value  New_Value 
:---------     :-------   :---------
Name            NULL       John
Age             NULL       45
Status          Active     Inactive
```

I need a output like

```
John     Name 
45       Age 
Inactive Status
```

Could you please help me out here.

Comment: It's not that clear to me. Which are the columns of your table? And with old and new value, do you mean you need an update?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a `NVL` to me ... Sample data in lines #1 - 5; query that does it begins at line #6.

```
SQL> with test (column_name, old_value, new_value) as
  2    (select 'Name'  , null    , 'John'     from dual union all
  3     select 'Age'   , null    , '45'       from dual union all
  4     select 'Status', 'Active', 'Inactive' from dual
  5    )
  6  select nvl(new_value, old_value) value,
  7         column_name
  8  from test;

VALUE    COLUMN
-------- ------
John     Name
45       Age
Inactive Status

SQL>
```

Comment: select
 decode (COLUMN_NAME Name, NVL2 (new_value , new_value  ,  old_value ) , NULL) as Name,
  decode (COLUMN_NAME ,age , NVL2 (new_value , new_value  ,  old_value ) , NULL) as Age,
   decode (COLUMN_NAME ,status , NVL2 (new_value , new_value  ,  old_value ) , NULL) as status
   from  test

Comment: I need an ouput from a query like this